# Is there a code-generator to create DataTable definition block from Excel Work sheet?

Tags: excel, ado.net, datatable, unit-testing, code-generation

Basically the thing I want to achieve is to have a data-table that I want to use in my unit tests. And when I run my unit tests, I do not want to read any excel file into a data-table -or any call to Db-.

So, I would like to have method that returns a data-table with the values that I can use in my test.

Is there already any written tool to read an excel sheet and generate a code that defines an ADO.Net DataTable?

Thanks,
burak ozdogan

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft ADO.NET driver for excel should do the trick: [How To Use ADOX with Excel Data from Visual Basic or VBA](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303814/EN-US/)

Answer (score 0):

I think QuickUnit does: http://www.quickunit.com/